# Why doesn't vim select inner parens but does for quotes?

Tags: vim

On line 1 I would rely on the command `ci"` to change the content inside the quotes and it works great.  However trying the same with parens does not work.  My fingers keep typing `ci(` and nothing happens.  What am I missing?  The text objects documentation tells me this should work. What am I missing?

```
  works("")
  fails()
```

**Found answer in comments**

This is the snippet I added in my .vimrc to make things work the way I expected.  Thanks for the help!

```
function New_cib()
    if search("(","bn") == line(".")
        sil exe "normal! f)ci("
        sil exe "normal! l"
        startinsert
    else
        sil exe "normal! f(ci("
        sil exe "normal! l"
        startinsert
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap ci( :call New_cib()<CR>
nnoremap cib :call New_cib()<CR>
```

Comment: @Tom Fancy, works for both breaklined `()`, inline `()` and with multiple `()` on the same line!

Comment: @timss just be careful, it won't work if you are past the brackets becaue `%` searches forwards.

Comment: @Tom Neither does `ci"` I believe, and `%ci(` doesn't continue to the next line and be "greedy".

Comment: As mentioned in a similar question, this is probably a a bug with `ci"`. I think ci stands for change inside. `ci{ ci[` and `ciw` (change word) all work according to `ci(`, and only change when the cursor is inside the characters.

Comment: Alright so it is indeed a duplicate.  What's the netiquette here?  Should I delete my question or just leave it so others can find it using slightly different vocabulary in their searches?

Comment: @GaryHaran Leave it be, it is beneficial for searches and such as you mentioned yourself :)

Comment: I can't seem to get this working in VSCode after adding it to my~/.vimrc and enabling vimrc in the Vim plugin. Any thoughts?